# How I can find Data Annotation attributes and their parameters using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, attributes, data-annotations

I have some data annotation attribute like this:

```
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "First name must be between 5 and 20 characters")]
```

How I can Find Data Annotation attributes and their parameters using reflection?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you have something like this:

```
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "First name must be between 5 and 20 characters")]
public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

To get the attribute and a property from it:

```
StringLengthAttribute strLenAttr = 
  typeof(Person).GetProperty("FirstName").GetCustomAttributes(
  typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false).Cast<StringLengthAttribute>().Single();


int maxLen = strLenAttribute.MaximumLength;
```