# How can reflection be used to determine if an attribute exists on a property?

Tags: c#, reflection

Similar: [How I can find Data Annotation attributes and their parameters using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7864662/1026459)

However, when attempting to gather the custom attribute, I always get back the same result. An empty `ScriptIgnore`.

```
PropertyInfo[] Properties = Entity.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo Property in Properties)
```

Upon debug, this line of code

```
var annotes = Property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute), false);
```

(I also tried using `true`)

looks like this

```
annotes | {System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnoreAttribute[0]}
```

However, Property is defined as a class property like this

```
public virtual Lot Lot { get; set; }
```

There is no `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute attached. Moreover, when I have tried this on Property when it was defined like this

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public virtual ICollection<Lot> Lots { get; set; }
```

I get back the same result as above

```
annotes | {System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnoreAttribute[0]}
```

How can I use reflection to determine if an attribute exists? Or other means if possible, I also tried

```
var attri = Property.Attributes;
```

but it did not contain any attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
public class TestAttribute
{
  [ScriptIgnore]
  public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }

  public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }

  public string SomeProperty3 { get; set; }

  [ScriptIgnore]
  public string SomeProperty4 { get; set; }
}
```

Define a static extension:

```
public static class AttributeExtension
{
  public static bool HasAttribute(this PropertyInfo target, Type attribType)
  {
    var attribs = target.GetCustomAttributes(attribType, false);
    return attribs.Length > 0;
  }
}
```

Put the following sample code into a method and it picks up the attribute correctly - including `ICollection` by the way:

```
  var test = new TestAttribute();
  var props = (typeof (TestAttribute)).GetProperties();
  foreach (var p in props)
  {
    if (p.HasAttribute(typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute)))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", p.Name, attribs[0].ToString());
    }
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
```

NOTE:  if you're using EF dynamic proxy classes, I think you will need to use `ObjectContext.GetObjectType()` to resolve to the original class before you can get the attributes, since the EF-generated proxy class will *not* inherit the attributes.

Comment: I tried this: `var objType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(typeof( T )); var propers = objType.GetProperties();` and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
var props = type.GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a is ScriptIgnoreAttribute))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: "No overload for `GetCustomAttributes` takes 0 arguments."

Comment: @TravisJ I tested it before posting and it works for me. Anyway, Try `GetCustomAttributes(false)`

Comment: - It does compile with `(false)`, however it is still empty. I think this might be a result of being lazy loaded by Entity Framework and not a fault of your code.

Comment: @TravisJ, I tested it again, and I can get the props with `ScriptIgnore` attributes.

Comment: - This is an issue with the way I am getting the type. EF returns a dynamic proxy and reflection doesn't seem to always play nicely with them.

Comment: @TravisJ: if EF is returning a dynamic proxy, then you have to use `ObjectContext.GetObjectType()` to resolve back to the original class type and then extract the attributes.